# kafka consumer on single node multi broker configuration

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Did somebody worked on kafka python with single node multi broker setup?

I was able to produce and consume the data with single node single broker settings but when I have changed that to single node multi broker data was produced and was stored in the topics but when I run the consumer code data was not  consumed.

Any suggestions on the above would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Note: all the configurations like producer , consumer and server properties were verified and are fine.

Producer code:

```
from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer

def producer():
    data = {'desc' : 'testing', 'data' : 'testing single node multi broker'}
    topic = 'INTERNAL' 
    producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v:json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'), bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092","localhost:9093","localhost:9094"])

    producer.send(topic, data)

    producer.flush()
```

Consumer code:

```
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer

def consumer():  
    topic = 'INTERNAL'
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092","localhost:9093","localhost:9094"])


    for data in consumer:
        print data
```

Server 1 config:  I have added two more server files like this with same parameters for other brokers with the difference in `broker.id`, `log.dirs` values.

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
num.network.threads=3
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Producer config:

```
metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
```

Consumer config:

```
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Comment: Could you please post your broker config and your python script? Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Hi Shizhz,  Details were updated as requested.

Comment: I re-formatted your config info, could you please have a check, just in case I made mistakes

Comment: `I have added two more server files like this with same parameters for other brokers with the difference in broker.id, log.dirs values`, did you change port?

Comment: And how do you start your brokers?

Comment: Yes, i did changed my port number in other config files.  This is how i have started the brokers in three different terminals .    nohup ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server1.properties > ~/kafka/kafka_1.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you receive the messages with a simple Kafka consumer ?

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh –bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 –topic INTERNAL –from-beginning
```

Or with this one :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --topic INTERNAL
```

If you get the messages with the second command, try to delete `/tmp/log.dir` of your brokers and log files in `/tmp/zookeepker/version-2/`. Then restart zookeeper and your brokers and create your topic again.

Comment: Worked like a charm.! Thank you so much.  However, i would like to configure 3 node 3 partition 3 replica cluster. Can you please advice on the ideal configuration and specs for setting up the cluster. Meanwhile i will go through the API documentation as well.

Comment: Nice, could you accept my answer, in order for me to get some points :)

Comment: For your question, you might make another post. It is not an easy question, and I am not expert.

Comment: I did.  I have removed the zookeeper folder completely and tested. Your suggestion also should work, since I don't have any other data related to kafka I just did that.